# Anonymous functions/delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates, c++-cli, anonymous-function

I'm converting my C# Windows Application to a C++\CLI app.

I'm stuck with 'converting' this code:

```
void LoadWindow(Mode mode) {
        if (timer != null && timer.Enabled) return;

        int currentIndex = Windows.IndexOf(panel.Controls[0]);
        int loadInex = 0, exitLeft = 0, entranceLeft = 0, stopLeft = 0;

        if (mode == Mode.Next)
        {
            loadInex = currentIndex == Windows.Count - 1 ? 0 : ++currentIndex;
            exitLeft = -((panel.Width / 2 - Windows[currentIndex].Width / 2) + Windows[currentIndex].Width);
            entranceLeft = panel.Width;
        }
        else
        {
            loadInex = currentIndex == 0 ? Windows.Count - 1 : --currentIndex;
            exitLeft = panel.Width;
            entranceLeft = -panel.Width;
        }

        stopLeft = panel.Width / 2 - Windows[loadInex].Width / 2;

        Windows[loadInex].Left = entranceLeft;
        panel.Controls.Add(Windows[loadInex]);

        timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 10;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (mode == Mode.Next)
            {
                if (exitLeft <= panel.Controls[0].Left)
                    panel.Controls[0].Left -= 50;

                if (stopLeft <= panel.Controls[1].Left)
                    panel.Controls[1].Left = panel.Controls[1].Left - 50 < stopLeft ? stopLeft : panel.Controls[1].Left - 50;

                if (exitLeft >= panel.Controls[0].Left && stopLeft >= panel.Controls[1].Left)
                {
                    panel.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
                    timer.Enabled = false;
                }
            }

            if (mode == Mode.Previous)
            {
                if (exitLeft >= panel.Controls[0].Left)
                    panel.Controls[0].Left += 50;

                if (stopLeft >= panel.Controls[1].Left)
                    panel.Controls[1].Left = panel.Controls[1].Left + 50 > stopLeft ? stopLeft : panel.Controls[1].Left + 50;

                if (exitLeft <= panel.Controls[0].Left && stopLeft <= panel.Controls[1].Left)
                {
                    panel.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
                    timer.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        });

        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

AFAIK C++\CLI doesn't support anonymous methods (I can't even take advantage of lambdas).

This wouldn't be a problem if the EventHandler delegate didn't use local variables in the LoadWindow function.

How can I implement this? I considered using a simple functor class, but is there a more 'elegant' way?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: C++ also doesn`t support events. Just pass your handler as a callback function

Comment: C++/CLI doesn't support this kind of code.  It **does** support calling C# code, any .NET language can use a class written in another language.  Taking advantage of that is an obvious way ahead.  Use C++/CLI to take care of the gritty unmanaged code interop.  Use .NET interop to take advantage of the capabilities of other languages.  Finding the right balance is a programmer's job.  You sound very capable of making that choice.